# Upgrade PSA to 2.4.x on Dynamics 365 9.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

We have upgraded our sandbox to Dynamics 9.0 and your PSA is at version 1.2.0.69. When we tried creating new project, we are getting "Object Reference" error. We found out that there is a known issue in PSA 1.2.x with v9.0 that we cannot create new project.
[image]

So we decided to upgrade PSA to 2.4. But doing so we are getting error and cannot upgrade.
[image]

Any suggestion appreciated! Thanks in Advance.